# Python: Identifying consecutive zeros in a column, delete their row and start new numbering

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by

I  have the following df and I want to split the data into trips.

```
In: df = pd.DataFrame([[1001,0.054012973,0],[1001,0.44923679,12],[1001,0,1],[1001,0,1],[1001,0.44676617,2],
[1001,1.8310822,1],[1001,0,1],[1001,0,11],[1001,0,1],[1001,0,20],[1001,0,1],[1001,0,54],[1001,10.0604029,2],
[1001,11.642113,0],[1001,0,1],[1002,0,2],[1002,1.23463449,23],[1002,1.8310822,1],[1002,0,1]],
columns=['Dev_ID','Speed','Duration'])

out:    Dev_ID  Speed   Duration
    0   1001    0.054013    0
    1   1001    0.449237    12
    2   1001    0.000000    1
    3   1001    0.000000    1
    4   1001    0.446766    2
    5   1001    1.831082    1
    6   1001    0.000000    1
    7   1001    0.000000    11
    8   1001    0.000000    1
    9   1001    0.000000    20
    10  1001    0.000000    1
    11  1001    0.000000    54
    12  1001    10.060403   2
    13  1001    11.642113   0
    14  1001    0.000000    1
    15  1002    0.000000    2
    16  1002    1.234634    23
    17  1002    1.831082    1
    18  1002    0.000000    1
```

The criteria for the splitting is having a speed value of 0 longer than 120 sec. So I have to go for each dev_ID and somehow check if there are consecutive zeros that last more than 120 sec. If the condition is true, I want to delete these rows (where zeros last more than 120 sec) and start a new id in the trip_ID column. So the results should look like this:

```
    Dev_ID  Speed   Duration    Trip_ID
0   1001    0.054013    0   10
1   1001    0.449237    12  10
2   1001    0.000000    1   10
3   1001    0.000000    1   10
4   1001    0.446766    2   10
5   1001    1.831082    1   10
6   1001    10.060403   2   11
7   1001    11.642113   0   11
8   1001    0.000000    1   11
9   1002    0.000000    2   12
10  1002    1.234634    23  12
11  1002    1.831082    1   12
12  1002    0.000000    1   12
```

Comment: This duration is in seconds or minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggested solution from @Dataman (many thanks) the code that worked for me is:

```
for Dev_ID, data in df.groupby("Dev_ID"): 
    for k, g in groupby(data.iterrows(), lambda x: x[1]['Speed']): #group consecutive speeds
        l = list(g)
        if l[0][1]['Speed'] == 0: # check if the consective speeds are zeros
           dur = sum(x[1]['Duration'] for x in l) # calculate how long speed 0 lasts
           if dur>120:
              zeros_idx.append([x[0] for x in l]) # save indexes where speed = 0 for long time
df.drop((item for sublist in zeros_idx for item in sublist),axis=0,inplace=True) #delete long stops
```

Answer (score 3):

I not totally sure I understood the condition, but I made a generic code that hopefully will be similar and you can adapt.

The key ideas are: using pd.shift() to get the difference, use np.where to get a list of indexes where sequences of speed difference = 0, split those indexes in contigous groups with get_contigous_index, then for every contigous group if the sum of duration is > 120 then change 'Trip_id'

I assumed your duration is in minutes, otherwise none of the intervals would be greater than 120

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
df = pd.DataFrame([[1001,0.054012973,0],[1001,0.44923679,12],[1001,0,1],[1001,0,1],[1001,0.44676617,2],
[1001,1.8310822,1],[1001,0,1],[1001,0,11],[1001,0,1],[1001,0,20],[1001,0,1],[1001,0,54],[1001,10.0604029,2],
[1001,11.642113,0],[1001,0,1],[1002,0,2],[1002,1.23463449,23],[1002,1.8310822,1],[1002,0,1]],
columns=['Dev_ID','Speed','Duration'])
df['Duration'] = df['Duration']*60
df['Trip_ID'] = df['Dev_ID']

def get_contigous_index(indexes):
    ranges = []
    for k,g in groupby(enumerate(indexes),lambda x:x[0]-x[1]):
        group = (map(itemgetter(1),g))
        group = list(map(int,group))
        ranges.append((group[0],group[-1]))
    return ranges

for Dev_ID, data in df.groupby("Dev_ID"):
    data['speed_diff'] = data['Speed'] - data['Speed'].shift(1)
    diff_0 = np.where(data['speed_diff'] == 0)[0]

    for contigousZeroes_range in get_contigous_index(diff_0):
        fst_idx, lst_idx = list(contigousZeroes_range)
        range_ = list(range(fst_idx,lst_idx+1))
        subgroup = data.loc[range_ ,data.columns]
        if not subgroup.empty:
            if subgroup['Duration'].sum() > 120:
                df.loc[range_,'Trip_ID'] = "a_different_id"
print(df)
```

this will print an dataframe like this:

```
    Dev_ID      Speed  Duration         Trip_ID
0     1001   0.054013         0            1001
1     1001   0.449237       720            1001
2     1001   0.000000        60            1001
3     1001   0.000000        60            1001
4     1001   0.446766       120            1001
5     1001   1.831082        60            1001
6     1001   0.000000        60            1001
7     1001   0.000000       660  a_different_id
8     1001   0.000000        60  a_different_id
9     1001   0.000000      1200  a_different_id
10    1001   0.000000        60  a_different_id
11    1001   0.000000      3240  a_different_id
12    1001  10.060403       120            1001
13    1001  11.642113         0            1001
14    1001   0.000000        60            1001
15    1002   0.000000       120            1002
16    1002   1.234634      1380            1002
17    1002   1.831082        60            1002
18    1002   0.000000        60            1002
```

Comment: Thank you @Dataman. Your code has helped me a lot. There are three things I had to change. 1) I didn't want to get indexes where sequences of speed difference = 0. Actually I wanted the indexes with speed = 0. 2) I wanted to delete these rows not give them different ids. 3) The left rows after the delete should get different id even though they belong to the same dev_id because it is a new trip now. So the code in its final version according to my objectives is: